# what "acuity of admission" means?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

whats is this sentences means? (in medical domain or hospital).

```
acuity of admission
```

main paragraph is:

Each instance of the data set is represented by attributes or features; for example,
in a particular project dealing with patient readmission, an instance of a patient
might be represented by (1) age, (2) gender, (3) length of stay in the hospital, (4)
acuity of admission, (5) Charlson comorbidity index, and (6) the number of
emergency department visits in the last 6 months prior to the current admission

Comment: It is usually better to address questions about **technical** terminology of a particular field to the experts in that field (in this case, medicine); they **know** the answer, while people with general interest in the language, such as the contributors to this site, can only make more or less reasonable **guesses** as to what the answer might be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it refer to the degree of acuity, that is, how severe the condition of the patient was at the time of admission?

acuity [ah-ku´ĭ-te]

1. Acuteness (see acute [def. 2]); the level of severity of an illness. This is one of the parameters considered in patient classification systems that are designed to serve as guidelines for allocation of nursing staff, to justify staffing decisions, and to aid in long-range projection of staffing and budget.

[thefreedictionary medical dictionary](https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/acuity)

Answer (score 1):

The etymology and meaning of *acuity* relate to *sharpness or acuteness*. Although the term is used in connection with quality of vision, hearing, thinking (for examples: acuity of thought = shrewd and thoughtful thinking; acuity of vision is a clinically measurable feature), it is also used to describe the urgency of admission to hospital, as M.G.S. suggests in their answer.

It is easy to imagine examples of different admission acuity. Admissions are urgent in emergency (e.g. heart attack), planned but not urgent (e.g. hip replacement), routine crucial (e.g. dialysis, radiation therapy), routine (e.g. regular checking of a condition).